# Stubing/Verifying a call with a FunctionalInterface/MethodReference argument

Tags: java, junit, mockito, stubbing, functional-interface

I never had to stub a call that accepts a functional interface/method reference as argument, so I just find out about the obvious incapacity for compare with "equals" these, aside from the reference comparison.

So how does one deal with this scenario during testing? Do we have to use any() either we want it or not?

```
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();

when(myColaborator.isCalledWith(comparator)).thenReturn("foo"); //This is not gonna work as long as the real call does not use theat very same reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to verify its collaborator whether has recieved an exactly `Comparator` in a simple test case since such a **communication protocol test** in a book of [GOOS](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) describes whether they will **work together** correctly. and then skip checking the rest of tests by using `any(Comparator.class)`. you can read it further in [Martin's blog](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TestsWithMockObjects):

> in the second test case is that I've **relaxed** the constraints on the expectation by using `withAnyArguments`. The reason for this is that the first test checks that the number is passed to the warehouse, so the second test need **not repeat** that element of the test. If the logic of the order needs to be changed later, then **only one test will fail**, easing the effort of migrating the tests. As it turns out I could have left `withAnyArguments` out entirely, as that is the default.